# Laravel 5.2 Array Validation with JSValidation

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, jsvalidation

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and validate my form via FormRequest. Additionally I  installed Proengsoft/JSValidation (https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) in Master Branch.

In my Form I have some fields, which are represented as arrays in my blade view:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    {!! Form::text('test[]', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 
                                             'placeholder' => "test")) !!}
@endfor
```

My form request for this fields looks as follows:

```
$rules = [
     [...]
    'test.*' => 'required',
     [...]
]
```

As i read on github, Proengsoft JSValidation supports Array-dot-notation in master branch, but it doesn't work for me. Unfortunately I don't get any error messages, so I think, that JSValidation ignores my fields. 
Serverside validation works as expected, so I don't think, that I have a mistake in my syntax.

I really hope, that someone has an idea, how to solve this problem.